# Build from parent directory with Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, devops

We are adapting monorepo to our project and we organized the code to three folders in which one of them is a shared_code between the two other projects.

When changes done in one of the project or the shared code a build triggered according the changes and a docker image is build and pushed to a docker registry.

```
project1
  -Dockerfile
  -Jenkinsfile
project2
  -Dockerfile
  -Jenkinsfile
shared_code
Jenkinfile
```

Since we using docker with a shared code, so the build should be done from parent directory as docker doesn't expect files from parent directory to be included.

Something like this should be done:

```
docker build -t project1:tag -f project1/Dockerfile .
```

This all still fine, but when using Jenkins I defined Jenkinsfile inside project1, so when I build project1 from Jenkins I fall to the issue that says docker doesn't access parent directory, and at the same time I don't wanna to take the Jenkinsfile to the parent folder in order to keep a certain organization.

Is there a way I could configure the directory that Jenkins takes for the build in the Jenkinsfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came back to answer my quetion if someone is facing the same challenge.

This is what helped me to build the image from Jenkins:

```
stage("Build image") {
        // Build the docker image with a tag
        steps {
            script {
                dockerImage = docker.build("project1:${env.BUILD_ID}", "-f ./project1/Dockerfile .")
            }
       }
 }
```